# VB.net How To Copy File To New Location

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

So im working on a project, with the aim to allow my user to select a mp3/wav file from there personal files, and save it in my programs directory so it can be accessed later.

```
Public Class Uploader_Control


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Upload.Click 'Button click triggers open file dialog
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\" 
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Upload A Song" 
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Audio Files|*.mp3; *.wav"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim New_Upload As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName 'Sets 'New_Upload' to the location of the selected file.

    Dim Upload_Path = Get_Upload_Path() 'Triggers function to find the destination path that i want the file to be copied too



End Sub
Function Get_Upload_Path() 'Tries to find the location for the file to saved too
    Dim Upload_Path As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    Upload_Path = Upload_Path.Substring(0, Upload_Path.LastIndexOf("/")) & "\Resources\" 

    Return Upload_Path
End Function
```

I have tried a few methods to try get it to copy however i cant seem to find a way to copy the file into a directory. If anyone can give any insight into a way i can achieve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to fix is your GetUploadPath.

```
Function Get_Upload_Path() as String
    Dim newPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    newPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath), "Resources")
    Return newPath
End Function
```

Here I am using the safe Path class methods to extract your folder and appending your Resource folder. Your code instead uses the character "/" and this is not the default path separator in Windows. Probably you will get an exception there

Finally you use File.Copy to copy a file, but remember, you should always give a filename to File.Copy source and destination parameters, not just a directory name

```
  if OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
     Dim newPath = Get_Upload_Path()
     Dim file = Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
     Dim newUploadName = Path.Combine(newPath, file)
     File.Copy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, newUploadName)
  End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, is by using System.IO.FileInfo:

```
Dim file as New FileInfo(path)
file.CopyTo(newPath)
```

Comment: Using the `File` class is easier because it doesn't require an instance.  One line of code is easier than two.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work, trying to keep things as close to the original:

```
    'Set up and open file dialog
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Upload A Song"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Audio Files|*.mp3; *.wav"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = String.Empty

    'Only proceed if OK pressed
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        'Get Destination Path
        Dim Upload_Path As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Resources")
        If IO.Directory.Exists(Upload_Path) Then
            'Copy file
            IO.File.Copy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, IO.Path.Combine(Upload_Path, IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)))
        End If
    End If
```

I added a check that the folder exists before you try to copy.

**Some other things you need to think about:**

If the folder does not exist, then think about creating it or issuing a message.

You are copying a file to your apps directory. Depending on where your app is located you could get a 'permission' problem.

Would a reference to the original files you load in work? A list of references to the audio files, load them in, without copy, then process as needed when the time comes?

Comment: Thank you a very useful answer! Iv succesfully got it to create and save my file to the bin/resources folder, does this mean that if i gave a exe to a user it would save a copy of there file even when the application is closed?

Comment: Regarding your questions i have already implemented validation that creates the resources folder incase its not there. I am worried about the permission problems though and dont really have the knowledge to address it. The program would most likely be stores in the 'programfilesx86' folder. Do you think i will run into any problems? and if so how can i avoid them. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want you can move it as well with:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(c:\\source\my.mp3, d:\\destination\my.mp3)
```

If not, use CopyFile instead.