# How can I grab the .pdf files from source to copy it under daily folder in destination?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file, copy

[click to see Folder directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04CHy.jpg) How can I grab the .pdf files from source to copy it under daily folder in destination? There are multiple {project folders} and each project folder need to copy to their corresponding destination.

These are my folder directory:

Source Example: root: {project folder}/.pdf   ,     {project folder1}/.pdf   ,    {project folder2}/.pdf   …….

Destination Example: root: {project folder}/daily folder/.pdf         ,          {project folder1}/daily folder/.pdf  ,         {project folder2}/daily folder/.pdf  …..

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CopyFolder(@"C:\Desktop\Source\pdf-reports", @"C:\Desktop\Destination\Parks");
            Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static public void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
        {
        if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                File.Copy(file, dest);
            }
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder, "l*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);


        foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                CopyFolder(folder, dest);
            }
```

Comment: Do you need to verify the file creation or modification date to determine the destination folder or this will be an automatic procedure that runs everyday and grab all the pdf files in the source folder and move it to the other folder?

Comment: @Mr.Alvaro This will be an automatic procedure that runs everyday like backup and grab pdf files in source and copy it to their folder under daily folder. Is that possible? I don't want all pdf file into one folder.

Comment: Show the code you have tried and explain where and how it did not behave as expected.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, it doesn't matter the pdf file date or creation or anything, all that you need is check the folder every day and grab all pdf files that are inside and move those to the daily folder.  If it is like this, is possible and its very simple,  I'll provide you with an answer in a couple hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net How To Copy File To New Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717522/vb-net-how-to-copy-file-to-new-location)

Comment: @Mary I have posted my code. Currently it does copy the files to destination {project folders} .  I want it to copy into the sub folder instead. Each {project folders} have a sub folder (daily folder).

Comment: In your code I am seeing that you are grabbing everything no just PDF, even folders.  So if you need to move everything use CopyDirectory instead.

Comment: @Mr.Alvaro But both source and destination doesn't have same folder structure. Source do not  have {daily folder} inside each {project folder}.

Comment: @Mr.Alvaro I have added an image to clearly understand what I'm trying to do. (please click the link above post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CopyFolder(@"D:\Origin", @"D:\Test");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void CopyFolder(string source, string destination)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);

            var files = new DirectoryInfo(source).GetFiles("*.pdf");
            string dailyFolder = "DailyFolder";
            string destinationDailyFolder = Path.Combine(destination, dailyFolder);
            foreach (var item in files)
            {                
                if (!Directory.Exists(destinationDailyFolder))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDailyFolder);
                item.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destinationDailyFolder, item.Name),true);
            }
            var Directories = new DirectoryInfo(source).GetDirectories();
            foreach (var directory in Directories)
            {
                CopyFolder(directory.FullName, Path.Combine(destination,directory.Name));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here it is.

```
Imports System.IO


'get the list of all pdf files from the source folder'
Dim FileList() As String = Directory.GetFiles("Replace for Source Folder", "*.pdf")
Dim FileName As String

'Set the root of the destination folder and create a new folder using as name the current date'
Dim DestPath As String = "Replace for Destination Folder" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Dim DestFolder As DirectoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(DestPath)

'go through each of the files and move those one by one'
For F = 0 To FileList.Length - 1
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileList(F))
    File.Move(FileList(F), DestPath & "\" & FileName.toString)
Next
```

`

Comment: thanks for the answer. It doesn't goes to the daily folder.

Comment: its not creating the folder?.  The code I put create a folder named with the current year, month and day for example today's folder will be 2019-5-31, then move the files into that folder.  If you can put your full code maybe I can review it and see where it is failing.

Comment: It does create the folder but is not what I want .  I want it to copy into the sub folder instead.  I have update my post with my code. Currently it copied to the {project folder} not in the sub folder. Each {project folders} have a sub folder (called daily folder).